# J-Meter - Moodle test scripts

Tags: jmeter, moodle

I just learned how to use J-Meter and i am loving work with it.

I have to do load testing for a moodle install .

I wonder if there are any set of jmeter scripts to test moodle that i can re-use or like some kind of benchmark scripts that are somehow advanced and that can help me test the moodle performance.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and links .

Comment: You've seen http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=119443 ?

Comment: i checked http://cvs.moodle.org/contrib/tools/jmeter/

pretty empty :(

Answer (score 0):

*J Meter script can not be reused as it requires 1 time recording option.Hence you need to record your script at least 1, then keep running the script with load increase gradually depending on your server capacity.*